# MySQL Query to find row duplicates based on condition with limit

Tags: mysql, duplicates, limit, conditional-statements, rows

I have two tables:

```
Members:

id     username    


Trips:

id    member_id     flag_status         created
                  ("YES" or "NO")
```

I can do a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  Trip.id, Trip.member_id, Trip.flag_status
FROM  
  trips Trip
WHERE   
  Trip.member_id = 1711
ORDER BY
  Trip.created DESC
LIMIT
  3
```

Which CAN give results like this:

```
id       member_id     flag_status
8        1711          YES
9        1711          YES
10       1711          YES
```

My goal is to know if the member's last three trips all had a flag_status = "YES", if any of the three != "YES", then I don't want it to count.

I also want to be able to remove the WHERE Trip.member_id = 1711 clause, and have it run for all my members, and give me the total number of members whose last 3 trips all have flag_status = "YES"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28b2d

In that sqlfiddle, when the correct query i'm seeking runs, I should see results such as:

```
 COUNT(Member.id)
        2
```

The two members that should qualify are members 1 and 3.  Member 5 fails because one of his trips has flag_status = "NO"

Comment: Place an table with example data on SQLfiddle also with multble member_ids..

Comment: "My goal is to know if the member's last three trips all had a flag_status = "YES", if any of the three != "YES", then I don't want it to count." you mean here that MySQL should always check the last records based on date (DESC) and filter those three records on flag_status = "Yes" or do i misunderstand that part..

Comment: member_id is a foreign key to the members table, and there is a unique on username and id in the members table.

Comment: All three have to equal YES to include that user the COUNT.

Comment: i don't understand how your comments anwsers mine...

Comment: I didn't really understand your question.  What do you mean by "filter those three records on flag_status = "YES".

Comment: Mysql should say... "Ok i'm checking member 3245 now... and let me look at his last three trips... in all three of those trips, does flag_status = "YES" in ALL of them? .... Then increment the number of members who meet the conditions plus one.    Then mySQL should do the same thing again with member 5219 and let's just say one of those member's last three trips has flag_status = "NO" do NOT increment + 1 and it should run for all members.

Comment: Ok your last comment answers mine second comment.. this question requires an inner self join or an subquery to get the results you need. what about example data to test query on place it on SQLfiddle... http://www.sqlfiddle.com   it more likely more people help you if you place example data there..

Comment: Added the sqlfiddle to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GROUP_CONCAT function, to obtain a list of all of the status ordered by id in ascending order:

```
SELECT
  member_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(flag_status ORDER BY id DESC) as status
FROM
  trips
GROUP BY
  member_id
HAVING
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(status, ',', 3) NOT LIKE '%NO%'
```

and then using SUBSTRING_INDEX you can extract only the last three status flags, and exclude those that contains a NO. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28b2d/5). I'm assuming that all of your rows are ordered by ID, but if you have a created date you should better use:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(flag_status ORDER BY created DESC) as status
```

as Raymond suggested. Then, you could also return just the count of the rows returned using something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  ...the query above...
) as q
```

Comment: Thank you fthiella!  By modifying your one line to:  SUBSTRING_INDEX(status, ',', 3) = "YES,YES,YES" I was able to get it to function as I desired!

Comment: @user2278120 you're welcome :) yes it's almost the same, using "YES,YES,YES" you will return all members that have at least three status flags, using NOT LIKE '%NO%' it will select also records that have just one or two "YES"

Comment: dont understand why this is marked as correct because this is assuming on id and not based on created (that the topicstarter wanted so this is by 
chance the results are correct because most likely off an AUTO_INCREMENT id..). should be `GROUP_CONCAT(flag_status ORDER BY created DESC) as status`

Comment: @RaymondNijland i didn't notice the created column, i've updated my answer, tnx

Comment: @thiella No problem +1 for hacking GROUP_CONCAT function like this

Answer (score 2):

Although I like the simplicity of fthiella's solution, I just can't think of a solution that depends so much on data representation. In order not to depend on it you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT member_id FROM (
    SELECT
      flag_status,
      @flag_index := IF(member_id = @member, @flag_index + 1, 1) flag_index,
      @member := member_id member_id
    FROM trips, (SELECT @member := 0, @flag_index := 1) init
    ORDER BY member_id, id DESC
  ) x
  WHERE flag_index <= 3
  GROUP BY member_id
  HAVING SUM(flag_status = 'NO') = 0
) x
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5fc8/1). Note I've slightly modified the fiddle to remove one of the users.

The process basically ranks the trips for each of the members based on their `id desc` and then only keeps the last 3 of them. Then it makes sure that none of the fetched trips has a `NO` in the flag_status. FInally all the matching meembers are counted.

Comment: Hi Mosty,  Thanks for your reply, however I am not able to understand it, even with your explanation.  Could you possibly explain it more in depth for a newbie at using mySQL variables?  I do want to run this against my actual db and see if it's faster than fthiella's solution, and depending on which one is faster I will select the appropriate one for the best answer.

Comment: If you need more info on UDV you should read a tutorial such as [this one](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/mysql/9780596101718/query-performance-optimization/user-defined_variables)